# Bulk move rows from one table to another with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy

I have two identical tables `post` and `old_post`. I have a query that checks for old posts.  I would like to move the rows returned by the query into the table `old_post` and delete the rows from table `post`.

I could solve this by iterating through the results returned by the initial query and update my results this way, however I am worried this is very inefficient and will start to cause me problems when I have 1,000+ rows. How can I efficiently "bulk move" rows from one table to another?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Query for old `Posts`.  Bulk insert `OldPosts` with the old `Posts'` data.  Bulk delete the old `Posts`.

```
keys = db.inspect(Post).columns.keys()
get_columns = lambda post: {key: getattr(post, key) for key in keys}

posts = Post.query.filter(Post.expiry > ts)
db.session.bulk_insert_mappings(OldPost, (get_columns(post) for post in posts))
posts.delete()
db.session.commit()
```

The `get_columns` function takes a `Post` instance and creates a dictionary out of the column keys and values.  Read the docs and warnings about using bulk [`insert`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.bulk_insert_mappings) and [`delete`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.delete) operations.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [Common Table Expressions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html) in PostgreSQL

```
WITH moved_posts AS (
    DELETE FROM post
    WHERE expiry > time_stamp
    RETURNING *
)
INSERT INTO old_post
SELECT * from moved_posts
```

CTE support for DELETE will be added in SQLAlchemy 1.1. In current release you can execute raw SQL

```
from sqlalchemy import text

sql = text('''
WITH moved_posts AS (
    DELETE FROM post
    WHERE expiry > ?
    RETURNING *
)
INSERT INTO old_post
SELECT * from moved_posts
''')
db.session.execute(sql, [time_stamp])
db.session.commit()
```

In SQLAlchemy 1.1 it would look like this

```
posts = Post.__table__
old_posts = OldPost.__table__
moved_posts = (
    posts.delete()
    .where(posts.c.expiry > ts)
    .returning(*(posts.c._all_columns))
    .cte('moved_posts'))
insert = (
    old_posts.insert()
    .from_select(
        [c.name for c in moved_posts.columns],
        moved_posts.select()
    ))
db.session.execute(insert)
db.session.commit()
```